# Is Whirlwind Water Stream Roaring Aura Sky Ripping Fist just Bang and Bomb combined techniques or is it something more?

Tags: one-punch-man

Bang and Bomb can perform an attack together called

*Whirlwind Water Stream Roaring Aura Sky Ripping Fist*

is this attack just supposed to be a combination of Whirlwind Iron Cutting Fist and  Water Stream Rock Smashing Fist power, or is it supposed to multiply them? Why their single attacks dont exhaust them, but the combined one does and can be used only once per battle? Is it because it demands more power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a special combination attack that utilizes both styles, but cannot be used by a single person due to the mastery of the styles required, and the immense amount of energy necessary just to provide the minimum necessary from one of the styles.

The individual styles appear to be "equipped" in a mechanics sense, such that they occupy the same "slot" and so cannot be used by the same person at the same time.

> Until Garou comes along, that is, and learns both styles. He eventually combines them together, with one on his right side and the other on his left, to create not only this combination attack style by himself, but subsequently creates his own (arrogantly titled) style. [image: Chapter 69 (webcomic), page 9]